# Error al almacenar un archivo en SQL

Tags: sql

Hola estoy tratando de hacer un query **INSERT** desde **C#** al parcer tengo un error de syntaxis, pero no lo veo. Alguien podría decirme si puede notar que es,  o qué estoy haciendo mal?

```js
//KyoTest
[HttpPost]
public JsonResult KyoTest(testsoru obj) {


  string cs = "Data Source=DMX87025;Initial Catalog=DB_PCC;Integrated Security=True";

  //HttpPostedFileWrapper file = test.file; //No es necesario lo pongas en una variable, pero lo pongo para mostrar el tipo de dato

  string query = "INSERT INTO Testsoru ([Name],[Wiw],[Formato],[Size],[FName],[Type])" +
    " VALUES ( " + obj.name + "," + obj.wiw + "," + obj.formato + "" +
    "," + obj.size + "," + obj.fname + ", " + obj.ftype + ")";


  System.Console.WriteLine("---------------------------AQUI!!!!!!!----------------------------" + query);
  using(SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(cs)) {
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query, con);

    con.Open();
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    con.Close();

  }

  return Json(new {
    success = true, message = "Success Baby Doll :* ;)"
  }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);

}
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Ejecuta: `System.Console.WriteLine(query)` y agrega el resultado a tu pregunta.  Pero, la verdad es que no es buena idea concatenar los valores directo en el SQL como haces. Es mucho mejor usar parámetros. Te evitas muchos problemas. Lo mas probable es que te falte alguna comilla en alguna parte.

Comment: Hola todos en el trabajo me han aconsejado exactamente eso de imprimir mi query para asegurarnos que esta... bien pero no he conseguido hacer esa impresión se que es de lo menos usual , pero en verdad no imprimo nada con ** System.Console.WriteLine**, algúna otra forma de imprimir? Por otro lado dice que use parametros algo así?... `cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Id", id)` ???

Comment: O simplemente, cuando la ejecución se detiene porque recibes la excepción, así como lo tienes en tu captura de pantalla, allí tienes la oportunidad de examinar el contenido de la variable `query`, y hasta puedes copiar su contenido.

Comment: Pero, ya que mencionas que esto es del trabajo, entonces se trata de código que se va a usar de verdad. Por favor, toma en serio lo que te aconsejo, y no concatenes los valores directamente en el SQL como lo haces. Si corriges eso, tu problema va a desaparacer, así como todos los riesgos adicionales asociados a esa mala práctica.

Comment: verifica que en obj ningun dato sea null

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Lo mas seguro es que tienes columnas de tipo varchar y no lo estas guardando como tal. Los valores varchar tienen que estar dentro de comillas simples `''`.

Supongamos que [Name],[Formato] y [FName] sean varchar, entonces seria asi:

```
  string query = "INSERT INTO Testsoru ([Name],[Wiw],[Formato],[Size],[FName],[Type])" +
    " VALUES ( '" + obj.name + "', " + obj.wiw + ",'" + obj.formato + "'" +
    "," + obj.size + ",'" + obj.fname + "', " + obj.ftype + ")";
```

Ahora bien, tu codigo es muy vulnerable por las injecciones sql, asi que lo cambias utilizando parametros para los valores y asi ejecutas el query de manera segura:

```
[HttpPost]
public JsonResult KyoTest(testsoru obj) {


  string cs = "Data Source=DMX87025;Initial Catalog=DB_PCC;Integrated Security=True";

  //HttpPostedFileWrapper file = test.file; //No es necesario lo pongas en una variable, pero lo pongo para mostrar el tipo de dato

  string query = "INSERT INTO Testsoru ([Name],[Wiw],[Formato],[Size],[FName],[Type])" +
    " VALUES (@name,@wiw,@formato,@size,@fName,@fType)";


  System.Console.WriteLine("---------------------------AQUI!!!!!!!----------------------------" + query);
  using(SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(cs)) {
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query, con);

    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@name",  obj.name ?? String.Empty);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@wiw",  obj.wiw);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@formato",  obj.formato ?? String.Empty);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@size",  obj.size);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@fName",  obj.fname ?? String.Empty);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@fType",  obj.ftype);
    con.Open();
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    con.Close();

  }

  return Json(new {
    success = true, message = "Success Baby Doll :* ;)"
  }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);

}
```

Comment: Me tira esto en una pantalla de error `An exception of type 'System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException' occurred in System.Data.dll but was not handled in user code

Additional information: The parameterized query '(@name nvarchar(4000),@wiw nvarchar(4000),@formato nvarchar(4000' expects the parameter '@name', which was not supplied. ` esto quiere decir que no estoy enviando bien los parametros y que llegan vacios?

Comment: Tienes que validar que el valor no sea null. Mira la respuesta actualizada.

Comment: Pues ya  intente con `?? String.Empty` algún otro tip o forma de verficar que no pase datos null? ya confirme tambien que este pasando el tipo de dato correctos.

Answer (score 1):

por lo que veo estas intentando insertar campos de tipo varchar o similar  en la BD, debes ingresarlos entre comillas simples, por ejemplo:

```
string query = "INSERT INTO Testsoru ([Name],[Wiw],[Formato],[Size],[FName],[Type])" +
" VALUES ('" + obj.name + "','" + obj.wiw + "','" + obj.formato + "" +
"'," + obj.size + ",'" + obj.fname + "','" + obj.ftype + "')";
```

Si tienes campos numéricos **NO** deben ir con comillas simples.

Espero te sirva.

Comment: Lo siento, pero mismo error u.u